# Не срабатывает функция привязанная к таймеру

Tags: c#, winforms

Функция срабатывает только при изменении размеров окна формы.

```
  public partial class MainForm : Form
  {
       Timer timer;
       bool flag;

       public MainForm()
       {
            InitializeComponent();
            simpleOpenGlControl1.InitializeContexts();
        }

        private void timerFunc(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            uint texture_text = 0;

            Gl.glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
            Gl.glClear(Gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            // ! Создаем картинку
            var text_bmp = new Bitmap(simpleOpenGlControl1.Width, simpleOpenGlControl1.Height);
            // ! Создаем поверхность рисования GDI+ из картинки
            Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(text_bmp);
            // ! Очищаем поверхность рисования цветом
            gfx.Clear(Color.Beige);
            // ! Создаем шрифт
            var font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSerif, 14.0f);
            // ! Отрисовываем строку в поверхность рисования (в картинку)

            if(flag)
            {
                gfx.DrawString("Привет, Мир!", font, Brushes.Black, new PointF(30, 30));
                flag = false;
            }
            else
            {
                gfx.DrawString("Прощай, Мир!", font, Brushes.Black, new PointF(30, 30));
                flag = true;
            }
            // ! Вытягиваем данные из картинки
            BitmapData data = text_bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, text_bmp.Width, text_bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

            // ! Включаем тектстурирование
            Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            // ! Генерируем тектурный ID
            Gl.glGenTextures(1, out texture_text);
            // ! Делаем текстуру текущей
            Gl.glBindTexture(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_text);
            // ! Настраиваем свойства текстуры
            Gl.glTexParameteri(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, Gl.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, Gl.GL_LINEAR);
            Gl.glTexParameteri(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, Gl.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, Gl.GL_LINEAR);
            Gl.glTexEnvf(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, Gl.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, Gl.GL_REPLACE);
            // ! Подгружаем данные из картинки в текстуру
            Gl.glTexImage2D(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, Gl.GL_RGBA, text_bmp.Width, text_bmp.Height, 0, Gl.GL_BGRA, Gl.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data.Scan0);

            text_bmp.UnlockBits(data);

            // ! Включаем смешивание
            Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_BLEND);
            Gl.glBlendFunc(Gl.GL_SRC_ALPHA, Gl.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

            // ! Делаем текстру текущей
            Gl.glBindTexture(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_text);

            // ! Рисуем прямогульник с нашей тектурой, на которой текст
            Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS);
                Gl.glTexCoord2f(0f, 1f); 
                Gl.glVertex2f(-1.0f, -1.0f);

                Gl.glTexCoord2f(1f, 1f); 
                Gl.glVertex2f(1f, -1.0f);

                Gl.glTexCoord2f(1f, 0f); 
                Gl.glVertex2f(1f, 1f);

                Gl.glTexCoord2f(0f, 0f); 
                Gl.glVertex2f(-1.0f, 1f);
            Gl.glEnd();

            Gl.glFlush();
            Invalidate();
        }

        void MainForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
            this.Dispose();
        }

        void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = 100;
            timer.Tick += timerFunc;
            timer.Start();
        }
   }
```

Comment: @rdorn Cпасибо.

Comment: @rdorn Да. Верно.

Comment: все есть в ответе, коментарии удаляю

Answer (score 2):

Метод `Control.Invalidate()`, согласно [**исходникам**](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,7141) вызывает перерисовку только того контрола к которому применен. Для того чтобы перерисовать дочерние контролы, нужно явно вызвать его перегруженный вариант `Invalidate(true)`, или применить его к тому контролу, который должен быть перерисован.

Отдельно хочу заметить, что если контрол-контейнер содержит много дочерних контролов, использовать первый вариант крайне не желательно, т.к. это может вызвать подвисание интерфейса. Более правильно применять `Invalidate()` у того контрола, в котором произошли изменения.

На крайний случай, вызывать перегрузку [**Invalidate(Rectangle rc, bool invalidateChildren)**](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,7192) с указанием прямоугольной области требующей перерисовки, это не сильно лучше `Invalidate(true)`, но при отсутствии прямой ссылки на необходимый контрол, позволяет более точно сфокусировать алгоритм перерисовки и снизить накладные расходы GDI+.